# Unable to open Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac on my MacPro

Tags: ms-office, mac-pro

I keep getting the following error message when I try to open any of my PowerPoint files on my Mac Pro.

[image: You can't open the application "Microsoft PowerPoint" because it is not responding]

Any suggestions?

Comment: it **could** be that it is still running/hung in the background. Have you tried the "universal fix?" In other words have you rebooted? If so have you then run the Office installer and selected "Repair?"

Comment: I turned off my computer and turned it back on. Same result. Are you saying I should delete and reinstall?

Comment: It was running in the background. Problem fixed thank you!!!